# Splitting and modifying a string from text file in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

In a school project I am making a Caesar's Cipher. The requirements I have to meet are the following: I need to read text from a text file, store it into a bi-dimensional array of strings with a maximum of 81 characters per line(80 useful + '\0') and 1000 lines, and then modify the content in order to cipher or decipher it. What if in a single line of text from the file I has more than 80 useful characters? I thought about making it read in a way that each space it reads transforms it into a '\0' and changes line in the array but I don't know if I can do it with fgets, instead of fgetc as I was doing it.

This is what I have right now:

```
int lerficheiro(char * texto[MAXLINHAS][MAXCARPORLINHA])
{
    char caractere;
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("tudomaiusculas.txt", "r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro ao ler ficheiro.");
        return (-1);
    }
    for(int linha = 0; linha < MAXLINHAS; linha++)
    {
        for(int coluna = 0; coluna < MAXCARPORLINHA; coluna++)
        {
            caractere = fgetc(fp);
            if(caractere == ' ') caractere = '\0'; break;
            if(caractere == '\n') caractere = '\0'; break;
            if(caractere < 'A' || caractere > 'Z')
            {
                printf("Erro ao ler, o ficheiro não contem as letras todas 
maiusculas");
                return (-1);
            }
            * texto[linha][coluna] = caractere;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Erro ao ler ficheiro.");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  An easy way to do all of the above is by calling: `perror()`

Comment: regarding: `if(caractere < 'A' || caractere > 'Z')`  This does not handle lower case characters not punctuation.  Suggest `if( !isalpha( caractere ) ) { // handle error }`  Note: the `isalpha()` is found in the header file: `ctype.h`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your array to 0 and make use of the fact that you select how many bytes you are reading using fgets. Just check the return value of fgets to see if you've reached the end of the file. 
Also note that you should not need to have your result array as a pointer, since array already are pointers (EDIT to mirror @user3629249 suggestions)
EDIT2: Edited code to take into account the new-line problem. Alo removed the -1 that was causing 79 char lines instead of 80

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINES 8000
#define HSIZE 81

int parse_file( FILE * inp_file, char res[MAX_LINES][HSIZE])
{
    int l = 0;
    int len = HSIZE;
    while( fgets( res[l]+(HSIZE-len), len, inp_file ))
    {
        len = HSIZE - strlen( res[l]);
        if( len <= 1)
        {
            l++;
            len = HSIZE;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char parsed_file[MAX_LINES][HSIZE] = {0};

    FILE * inp_file;

    inp_file = fopen( "file_to_parse.txt", "r");
    if( inp_file == NULL)
    {
        printf( "Failed to read input file...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    parse_file( inp_file, parsed_file);

    fclose( inp_file);

    for( int i=0; parsed_file[i][0] != 0; i++)
        printf( "line %04d: %s\n", i+1,parsed_file[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want you could also replace the new line in your parsed_file with something like this

```
char *pos;
while( (pos = strchr( line, '\n'))
    *pos = ' ';
```

With test file:

```
This is a random file that I'm testing out for the pure randomness of random files.
Still reading, m'kay man lets get going!!!!!!!!!!! So last day the craziest thing happened, let me tell you about it....
```

and output

```
line 0001: This is a random file that I'm testing out for the pure randomness of random fil
line 0002: es.
Still reading, m'kay man lets get going!!!!!!!!!!! So last day the craziest 
line 0003: thing happened, let me tell you about it....
```

Take care that the printf will still print the newline character

Comment: NEVER use `while( !feof(...) )`  As it does not do what you are expecting.  Suggest: `while( fgets( res[l++], HSIZE-1, read ) )`  Also note: `read` is a well known C library function so 'shouldn't' be use as a variable name.

Comment: Wonderful, it works! There is only one thing left, since In my text files some of the lines end with '\n' before the strlen limit, it prints the newline before '\0', I tried to remove it with strtok but couldn't. Any help?

Comment: Cleaner to use `#define HSIZE 80` and then `char parsed_file[MAX_LINES][HSIZE+1]...` and adjust the remainder as necessary.

Comment: @Luis Gaspar I've edited the answer to take into account newline characters. To do this you need to check the length of the line at every fgets and switch to new line after you reach 80

Comment: removing a newline character, before the NUL terminator byte is easily done with: `str[ strcspn( str, '\n' ) ] = '\0';`  where `str` is the address of the string to have the newline removed from

Comment: @user3629249 I think this would work only if 1 newline character is present in the string. I don't see a way to implement this without a loop unless there is some function that does it implicitly. Also replacing it with a NULL seems to contradict the requested behavior for the function.

Comment: the OPs code returns if a newline character is read, without first terminating the input string.  So there will never be multiple newlines in a entry in `texto[][]`